# Mockito Spring Data Web Support

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, mockito, mockmvc

I am new to Mockito and have a bit of a problem concerning the Spring Data Web Support.

I have the following function in my controller.

```
@DeleteMapping("/")
public MyObject delete(@RequestParam("id")MyObject object){
...do something
}
```

whats happening here (in real usecases) is decribed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web).

The problem is, when i use MockMvc and Mockito in my unitTests, there is no database and no persistence Repositories. How can i make Spring use a mockRepository to replace the id handed over in `/?id=1` by a MyObject-instance of my choice.

This is what the Test looks like:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.mine.OrgUnitController;
import com.mine.OrgUnitService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrgUnitControllerTest2 {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Mock
    SomeService someService;
    @InjectMocks
    MyController controller;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_delete() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(delete("/?id=1")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: Can you add an example of your unit test?

Comment: @alayor sure, i did so.

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak yes i do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution is very easy and it only cost me 2 Days. ;)
To make the SpringDataWebSupport work spring uses `org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter` wich is a ConversionService. The next thing to know is that MockMvc accepts a ConversionService via `setConversionService()`. so the Only thing left to do was to write my own ConversionService wich is actually very easy. I extended `DefaultFormattingConversionService` like this:

```
public class MockSpringDataWebSupport extends DefaultFormattingConversionService {
    /**
     * @param converters {@link Converter Converters} that shall be added to this {@link ConversionService}
     */
    @SafeVarargs
    public MockSpringDataWebSupport(Converter<? extends Object, ? extends Object>... converters) {
        for (Converter<? extends Object, ? extends Object> converter : converters) {
            this.addConverter(converter);
        }
    }
}
```

thisway i could handover any coustom converter that fits my needs for Testing. In this special case i used:

```
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setConversionService(new MockSpringDataWebSupport(new Converter<String, MyObject>() {
                @Override
                public OrgUnit convert(String source) {
                    return new MyObject();
                }
            })).build();
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To return a MyObject for a given id, you can use `when(…​.).thenReturn(…​.)`. So when you've a method in SomeService to find MyObject by id, you can stub this and return values.

```
// When the get method is called, it will return MyObject
when(someService.get(id)).thenReturn(new MyObject());
```

Comment: sorry but you did not get it.

Comment: replacing the id by the MyObject is done by the Spring DI before calling the Controllermethod and it does not use `SomeService` but an implementation of `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository` which in a real world scenarion it would find on the classpath but my MockMvc does not use it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier for you if you just use `Mockito` instead of `Mockito` + `MockMvc`.

You could do something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrgUnitControllerTest2 {
    @Mock
    SomeService someService;
    @InjectMocks
    MyController controller;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_delete() throws Exception {
        //given
        given(someService.delete(1)).willReturn(true); //or successful response

        //when
        MyObject response = controller.delete(1);

        //then
        assertTrue(OK, response.getStatus())
    }
}
```

Comment: this works, but it does not test, what i want it to test. The intention of the test is to verify that a request to `/?id=1` ends up in calling controller.delete() wich in your case is not part of the Test anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably need to set `setCustomArgumentResolvers` in `MockMvc` object, like this:

```
@Before
  public void init() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
          .standaloneSetup(controller)
          .setCustomArgumentResolvers(new HandlerMethodArgumentResolver(){...})
          .build();
   }
```

You need to figure out which class is implementing `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and then use that in the `init()` method above.

You can take a look at [this](https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/01/29/using-custom-arguments-in-spring-mvc-controllers/) resource.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i make Spring use a mockRepository to replace the id handed over in /?id=1 by a MyObject-instance of my choice

You can do that by mocking `WebConversionService`, which will avoid the database lookup through the entity repository `findById`. You will also be able to set which instance you would like to use without fetching it from the database. For more details about how to mock this service take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169405/1833705).